# Get snapshots of only changed frames using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to capture "changed" frames from an MP4 files using FFmpeg. I have a video which is basically a sequence of slides/screenshots. I only want to capture the frame if it has changed. It would be nice to also check for percentage change and capture only if it has changed more than 10% for example.

Answer (score 5):

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -filter_complex "select=gt(scene\,0.5)" "frames/%04d.jpg"
```

Above selects frames that introduce scene change.

Comment: `"select=gt(scene\,0.1)"` for 10% change.  Handy reference: https://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_thumbnails_select_scene_iframe.php

Comment: I tried using this, but it despite detecting duplicates, it seems to output all the frames. I am using a QuickTime file. Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay Add `-vsync drop` in to the command. The image sequence muxer duplicates frames based on the frame timestamps in order to maintain a constant output framerate. Adding `-vsync drop` destroys the timestamps and makes the muxer output frames at a constant rate.

Answer (score 2):

I generated an image per frame and remove duplicated using MD5 hash:

```sh
ffmpeg -i "file.mkv" -r 1 "preffix-%d.png"
md5sum *.png | sort | awk 'BEGIN{lasthash = ""} $1 == lasthash {print $2} {lasthash = $1}' | xargs rm  # From https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192701/209677
```

Depending on your video, you might need to tune the rate of change (0.1 in this case). Also, note the `-vsync vfr`.

```sh
ffmpeg -i file.mkv -vsync vfr -filter_complex "select=gt(scene\,0.1)" "slides-%04d.jpg"
```

Comment: The second command give me `rm: missing operand`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There is no `rm` on the command. Are you using this with `xargs` or `find`?

Answer (score 2):

The top voted answer outputs each unique frame multiple times and fails to output the first frame.

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -filter_complex "select=bitor(gt(scene\,0.5)\,eq(n\,0))" -vsync drop "frames/%04d.jpg"
```

This outputs each unique frame once, and will include the first frame in the video.